# Session variable in delegate async function inside a webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asynchronous, delegates

I am developing my application in ASP.NET 4.5. I've created a delegate function like the follows:

```
private delegate void CounterDelegate(List<int> temp, int id);
private CounterDelegate sfd;


public Foo(){
  sfd = new CounterDelegate(this.Counter);
}
```

I Call the function like that:

```
 sfd.BeginInvoke(temp, id, null, null);
```

The Goal is to run the 'Counter' function in async fashion inside an async function. This works fine this way. The function is called from a function that's within a webservice. My issue is with Sessions.

My function:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public  void Counter(List<int> temp, int id)
{
   if (Session["user"] == null)
   {
      // do something
   }
}
```

The problem is that Session equals to null  and when I try to initialize it like that:

```
 Session["user"] = new List<int>();
```

I get **NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code**  exception. I did try to put it in try catch and initialize it in the catch block the problem is that I can't continue to run the code after that because it leaves the function.

Is there anyway to initialize and make Session variables available as if I would have done it in a regular non-async function in a webservice?

Comment: I think you will need to use something like `SynchronizationContext.Send()` to get back to the request's synchronization context, which I believe includes `Session`.

Comment: Can you maybe initialize your Session variables in Global.asax?